# Let's talk about struct

Tags: c

I know what struct is but haven't seen such use of it. 
Can any one explain to me in more details what that code do ?

```
static struct option const long_options[] =
{
  {"all", no_argument, NULL, 'a'},
  {"kernel-name", no_argument, NULL, 's'},
  {"sysname", no_argument, NULL, 's'},  /* Obsolescent.  */
  {"nodename", no_argument, NULL, 'n'},
  {"kernel-release", no_argument, NULL, 'r'},
  {"release", no_argument, NULL, 'r'},  /* Obsolescent.  */
  {"kernel-version", no_argument, NULL, 'v'},
  {"machine", no_argument, NULL, 'm'},
  {"processor", no_argument, NULL, 'p'},
  {"hardware-platform", no_argument, NULL, 'i'},
  {"operating-system", no_argument, NULL, 'o'},
  {GETOPT_HELP_OPTION_DECL},
  {GETOPT_VERSION_OPTION_DECL},
  {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
};
```

Comment: It's an initializer for an array of structs.

Comment: In C, `struct` is basically part of the name of a type. so this is a `static`, `const` array (`[]`) of `struct option`s, named `long_options`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an initialization of a static array of `struct option` elements. This structure will have four elements (`char*`, other, a pointer, and a character), and these are the values. Note the array is ended with a NULL value to prevent searchs throug it to pass beyond end, and note also how some constants relevant for the struct are used.

Answer (score 1):

It defines a static (that is, invisible in other .c modules) constant array, named `long_options`, of structures of type `option`. Individual lines like `{"all", no_argument, NULL, 'a'}` are elements of type `struct option`. I see no problem here.

Answer (score 1):

This code is creating an array of struct option. Each row contains the value of an item in that array.

From the code I assume struct option something like this

```
struct option
{
    const char * option_name;
    enum argument_type  argument;
    void * pointer; //not enough context
    char short_option;
};
```